# How to run pwa developed with ionic on android device

Tags: ionic-framework

I have connected my android phone to the same wifi as my laptop is connected.
and i execute ionic serve --devapp
the expectation is to be able to run my ionic PWA on my android device.

Comment: how you create the project using ionic?

Comment: ionic start command

Answer (score 0):

Very simple :

```
ionic cordova run android
```

Note : 
This command will automatically integrate cordova in ionic project.

Manually integrate cordova :

```
ionic integrations enable cordova
```